# Add role privileges of the custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, dashboard, events, privileges

I wonder if it is possible when adding a new role `add_role()` I can assign to it a privileges to add, edit, delete posts of a custom type.

To be specific.
I want to add a role 'volunteer coordinator' that can edit, add, delete events. Event is a custom post type.

The things that I managed to do is to assign privileges as a editor but this only works on the posts and the pages but not a custom posts events.
I have a whole dedicated event section in the dashboard that I cannot see when logged as a volunteer coordinator.
How can I make it visible, that volunteer coordinator can work with that section?

Or is there a way somewhere in the event plugin to make it visible for the new role?

Thank you

Comment: Which events plugin are you using?

Comment: [Events Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/events-manager/)

Comment: Is that up to plugin? Could I make privileges like a editor and somewhere define in the plugin that is readable by editor?